# Why are my UV maps rotated like this?

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

I tried to model and texture a milk package, but for some reason **some** of my faces UVs seem to be rotated.

I exported my UV Map to photoshop, laid the textures on it but some of them are stretched, rotated or not even applied...

What did i do wrong/how can i fix this?

PS: I rotated the image texture by 180° because this way most of the texture fit, only some are not working.

Front and back of my milk:

[image: "Front" view]
[image: "Back" view]

Comment: It would be nice if you could upload the  blend file for further inspection.

Comment: Blend file:
http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=197767

Comment: file DNE anymore

Comment: Maybe you could manually rotate those wrong UV vertices to fix it?

Comment: "this file does not exist anymore on the server!"